# Problem with SSL certificate on a Spring Boot 2 application deployed on Tomcat 8.0.x

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, tomcat

I have a Spring Boot application deployed as war on a Tomcat 8.0. application server.

From this application I'm calling another service, via HTTPS / REST and I have sucessfully installed the certificate in keystore.

When I execute the application and the call to this other service is made, it returns

`org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for https://cxm-hbase-service.santander.pre.corp/xxxxxxx/getLastNotificationTag: Certificate for <cxm-hbase-service.santander.pre.corp> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: [ *.santander.pre.corp]; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Certificate for <cxm-hbase-service.santander.pre.corp> doesn't match any of thesubject alternative names: [ *.santander.pre.corp]`

- First thing that surprise me is that it says that cxm-hbase-service.santander.pre.corp doesn't match *.santander.pre.corp which actually does.
- Second, I have tried to run the same application as a standalone jar and it works. And I have also tried to make the same HTTPS call inside another old application build with Spring Boot 1 and deployed in the same tomcat, and it works

Obviously, if I add the NoopHostnameVerifier it works, but my goal is to make it work with validation

Did somebody experienced something similar?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Can you confirm that the IP addresses for the  host(s) are listed in the certs Subject Alternative Name section ?

Comment: @0xadecimal: error message shows only a wildcard DNS in the SAN, but since the URL is clearly using a DNS-form hostname (aka authority) why on earth would having _addresses_ in SAN matter at all? Eduardo+Yogesh: note part of your error message disappeared because in 'blockquote' format, text in angle brackets is treated as an invalid HTML tag and deleted; it's better to use 'code' markdown (the {} button) which also preserves line layout, for program data as well as actual code.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 prior to edits on the question it was not clear that it was the host name and not  the IP that was being presented.